# Create a graph Blazor component with export in PDF and PowerPoint

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I'm developing an application in `Blazor WebAssembly`. I have to create a congress plan based on the input from the clients. I have a lot of them. I want to achieve a result like the following image

[image]

Using HTML is quite simple: I can create a `table` and then add some `CSS` for the arrows and the labels. But the requirement is to export this plan in PowerPoint and possibly as an image or PDF.

Then, I have 2 questions:

- is there any (free) component around that can produce this kind of graph?
- if I want to create the graph from scratch, what way can I follow?

Comment: Your first question is off topic (library recommendations) and your second question is too broad.

Answer (score 2):

1. I do not know any component/library that can do this.
2. Just a quick idea: Generate the graph as SVG (you can render inline svg markup with Blazor just like HTML markup) and then use a JS library like svg-export to generate the PDF from your svg element or store it as an image. From there you can try to generate a PowerPoint file programmatically and include this exported svg image into it. (I don't know how to create the PowerPoint programmatically , but a quick search shows up a lot of results regarding this topic here on Stack Overflow.